# 2nd order partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The given function is

$$f(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3) = \sin(\omega \cdot x^0 -k_1 \cdot x^1 -k_2 \cdot x^2 - k_3 \cdot x^3)$$

Now the question says to calculate "all partial derivatives up to second order". So, the part where I'm confused is how many partial derivatives are there?

Is it 20? I got following partial derivatives

$f_{x^0},f_{x^1},f_{x^2}, f_{x^3}$ as first order derivatives

$f_{x^0x^0}, f_{x^0x^1}, f_{x^0x^2}, f_{x^0x^3}, f_{x^1x^0}, f_{x^1x^1}, f_{x^1x^2}, \ldots, f_{x^3x^3}$, as second derivatives.

Am I on the right tract or did I got completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there should be ten second order partial derivatives, which could be arranged in a symmetric martrix that is 4 by 4.

Comment: 10?? but there are 16 elements on 4X4 matrix.. or did I misunderstood it?

Comment: oh.. never mind!! i got it!! thanks!!